# JDK 8 support at DIY cartridge in OpenShift

Tags: openshift, java-8

I know [WildFly cartridge doesn't have JDK support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23230511/jdk-8-support-for-wildfly-8-1-openshift-cartridge), but can I somehow install Java 8 at experimental DIY cartridge? java-1.7.0 is the latest version available at /usr/lib .

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Java 8 is now available by default with DIY. You just need to set PATH as given below in your **/.openshift/action_hooks/start.sh**

```
export JAVA_HOME=/etc/alternatives/java_sdk_1.8.0
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: I have three places for `action_hooks` which one is the correct one? `./app-root/runtime/repo/.openshift/action_hooks` `./app-deployments/2015-09-23_11-04-35.405/repo/.openshift/action_hooks` `./jbossews/template/.openshift/action_hooks`. Please guide

Comment: This doesn't work for me. After setting those export I still see that my environment uses OpenJDK, any ideas?

Answer (score 29):

If you want an specific JDK version you can download it and set the environment variables:

```
cd $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR
wget --no-check-certificate --no-cookies --header "Cookie: oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie" http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u5-b13/jdk-8u5-linux-x64.tar.gz
tar -zxf jdk-8u5-linux-x64.tar.gz
export PATH=$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/jdk1.8.0_05/bin:$PATH
export JAVA_HOME="$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/jdk/jdk1.8.0_05"
```

Thanks to [this cartridge](https://github.com/ichristo/openshift-wildfly-cartridge-jdk8/blob/master/bin/util).

As @youssef points out, you should also add this lines to .openshift/action_hooks/start:

```
export JAVA_HOME="$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/jdk/jdk1.8.0_05"
export PATH=$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/jdk1.8.0_05/bin:$PATH
```

UPDATE: now OpenShift has added alternative runtimes, you can skip downloading your own:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/etc/alternatives/java_sdk_1.8.0
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: I would expect that the exports should go also to the start hook. correct me if am wrong !

Comment: I think it's not necessary, those exports were enough for me.

Comment: Is that in a new DIY ? and even after restarting cartridge ?

Comment: I also needed to add "export OPENSHIFT_WILDFLY_JDK8=$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/jdk1.8.0_31/" into .openshift/action_hooks/pre_start_wildfly

Comment: See answer by sathish - the DIY package now includes JDK 1.8, just not on the path by default.

Comment: the only note of caution on the above solution is that if someone using free account, it may very quickly eat up all the disk space and leave one stranded. So sticking to the embedded idk make more sense to save time going forward.

Answer (score 9):

Hi I want to update the answer above, since I had the same need to update the JDK for my Vert.x application. Since it's totally written in Java8 (Vert.x code looks much better with it) I started to experiment a little with Openshift, until I met the issue that juan reported.

However I had to fix some stuff and updated to JDK1.8u20:

```
// connect with SSH to your application, then
cd $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR 
wget --no-check-certificate --no-cookies --header "Cookie: oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie" http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u20-b26/jdk-8u20-linux-x64.tar.gz
tar -zxf jdk-8u20-linux-x64.tar.gz
export PATH=$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/jdk1.8.0_20/bin:$PATH
export JAVA_HOME=$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/jdk1.8.0_20/

// then depending on your cartridge you need to exec the following command
echo $JAVA_HOME > $OPENSHIFT_{cartridge}_DIR/env/JAVA_HOME

// in my case was
// echo $JAVA_HOME > $OPENSHIFT_VERTX_DIR/env/JAVA_HOME
// for Wildfly I presume it is
// echo $JAVA_HOME > $OPENSHIFT_WILDFLY_DIR/env/JAVA_HOME
```

Answer (score 3):

This does not work if you are using Maven with the DIY-Cartridge.

If you look at the mvn command in "/usr/bin/mvn" on your box you will see that mvn resets $JAVA_HOME when executed.

```
#!/bin/sh
prog=$(basename $0)
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java
export JAVACMD=$JAVA_HOME/bin/java
export M2_HOME=/usr/share/java/apache-maven-3.0.4
exec $M2_HOME/bin/$prog "$@"
```

**UPDATE**

After a bit of head scratching I was finally able to work out how to run a java8 application using Maven on a DIY cartridge. As we know the mvn executable on usr/bin is no good, we simply download our own. Once we have our own version of Maven which respects JAVA_HOME then we are good to go. Here are my action_hooks...

**pre_start**

```
#!/bin/bash
cd $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR

#Download Maven If not already installed
if [ ! -d apache-maven-3.3.3 ]; then
  wget http://www.eu.apache.org/dist/maven/maven-3/3.3.3/binaries/apache-maven-3.3.3-bin.tar.gz
  tar -zxf apache-maven-3.3.3-bin.tar.gz
fi

#Download Java8 If not already installed
if [ ! -d jdk1.8.0_05 ]; then
  wget --no-check-certificate --no-cookies --header "Cookie:    oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie" http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u5-b13/jdk-8u5-linux-x64.tar.gz
  tar -zxf jdk-8u5-linux-x64.tar.gz
fi
```

**start**

```
export PATH=$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/jdk1.8.0_05/bin:$PATH
export JAVA_HOME="$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/jdk1.8.0_05"


cd $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR
echo -e  "<settings>\n <localRepository>$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR</localRepository>\n</settings>\n" > settings.xml

$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/apache-maven-3.3.3/bin/mvn -f $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR/pom.xml clean package -s $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/settings.xml

nohup java -jar $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR/target/**YOUR_FAT_JAR**.jar > $LOG 2>&1 &
```

Hope this helps anyone else who put as many hours in to this as I did :)

Answer (score 0):

The default wildfly 8 (8.2.1) cartridge now supports JDK8 out-of-the-box.