# WAR containing spring boot application manually deployed on openshift tomcat does not work

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, tomcat7, openshift, spring-boot

I created a Spring Boot application, then I created a war.

On my local server the app works correctly.

I added this app to a JBOSSEWS cartridge by renaming it ROOT.war, putting it in the webapps directory using git and restarting the server.

But I always have a 404 not found.

The tomcat logs are :

```
new-host-3:jbossews JARVIS$ rhc tail jbossews
Aug 30, 2014 3:27:25 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.54
Aug 30, 2014 3:27:25 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive /var/lib/openshift/540178a84382ec94b8000b75/app-        root/runtime/dependencies/jbossews/webapps/ROOT.war
Aug 30, 2014 3:27:37 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deployment of web application archive /var/lib/openshift/540178a84382ec94b8000b75/app-root/runtime/dependencies/jbossews/webapps/ROOT.war has finished in 11,864 ms
Aug 30, 2014 3:27:37 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-127.10.90.1-8080"]
Aug 30, 2014 3:27:37 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 12059 ms
```

Comment: Which url do you invoked localy, and which one on JBOSSEWS?

Comment: Locally : localhost:8080/greeting. Online : jbossews-flco.rhcloud.com/greeting.

Comment: The `ROOT.war` is available on the `/` I suspect you renamed it from `greeting.war` to `ROOT.war`?

Comment: No, I renamed app.war to ROOT.war, greeting is a parameter passed to the Spring MVC controller to the RequestMapping.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that your main class Application extends `SpringBootServletInitializer`

> Initialize the servlet
>
> By converting this into a WAR file with no XML files, you need a different signal to the servlet container on how to launch the application.

```
import org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer;

public class HelloWebXml extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

}
```

> `HelloWebXml` is a pure Java class that provides an alternative to creating a `web.xml`. It extends the `SpringServletInitializer` class. This extension offers many configurable options by overriding methods.

Source: [Spring.io Guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/convert-jar-to-war/)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you removed the pom.xml file and the src/ directory, so that it will deploy your ROOT.war file when you do a git push.  You can check out this kb article for further information: https://help.openshift.com/hc/en-us/articles/202399740-How-to-deploy-pre-compiled-java-applications-WAR-and-EAR-files-onto-your-OpenShift-gear-using-the-java-cartridges

Comment: I used this post to put my war on OpenShift, I well removed the pom.xml and src dir. I tried with tomcat and jboss, the problem is the same.

Comment: Do you have your code posted somewhere publicly?  Does the spring boot application work on your local development server?

Comment: No the code is not public (no interest), it is a very simple spring boot project to test spring boot on Openshift.
Firstly I made this [project](http://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/) and I converted the jar to a war using this [guide](http://spring.io/guides/gs/convert-jar-to-war/) and finally I put the war on OpenShift using this [tuto](https://help.openshift.com/hc/en-us/articles/202399740-How-to-deploy-pre-compiled-java-applications-WAR-and-EAR-files-onto-your-OpenShift-gear-using-the-java-cartridges) from OpenShift. Locally the .war works very well.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and was able to solve it by copying the .openshift directory from the original git-repo into the repo folder of the tar.gz. So afterwards my directory structure looked something like this:

`myApp.tar.gz
 - dependencies
 - - jbossews
 - - - - webapps
 - - - - - ROOT.war
 - repo
 - - .openshift
 - - - - markers
 - - - - - java7
 ...`

I think the problem in my case was, that tomcat tried to deploy the application with JDK 1.6, as this seems to be the fallback, when there is no java7 file in the markers directory...

Answer (score 0):

There are reasons:

1. Check you don't use Java 8 if so turn it to Java 7 or [DIY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23894323/jdk-8-support-at-diy-cartridge-in-openshift). When you using Java 8 container will not deploy war (tested myself).
2. Use SpringBootServletInitializer as @Jakub said.