# Jboss runs using java 6 instead of java 8

Tags: java-8, openshift-cartridge

I changed the file name .openshift/markers/java7 to java8 but now when i start the gear it uses java 6 instead of java 8 and fails when trying to load classes with java 8 code. How can i make the app use java 8?
I use Tomcat 6 (JBoss EWS 1.0) in openshift.

Comment: Same problem. Have you solved it?

Comment: Same Problem. Did you find any solution?

Comment: I used DIY cartirdge and installed tomcat myself and configured it to use java 8

Answer (score 0):

As stated in [openshift documentation](https://developers.openshift.com/en/tomcat-markers.html) about the java8 tomcat marker:

> Will run Tomcat with Java8 if present. If no marker is present then the baseline Java version will be used (currently Java6)

It seems that Java 8 is not present in your server, and that is why it is falling back to Java 6.

All you need to do is to make Java 8 available in your server (as described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23894323/jdk-8-support-at-diy-cartridge-in-openshift)):

```
rhc ssh yourAppNAme


cd $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR
cdwget --no-check-certificate --no-cookies --header "Cookie: oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie" http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u5-b13/jdk-8u5-linux-x64.tar.gz
tar -zxf jdk-8u5-linux-x64.tar.gz
export PATH=$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/jdk1.8.0_05/bin:$PATH
export JAVA_HOME="$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/jdk/jdk1.8.0_05"
```

And add the folowing lines to your start action hook (.openshift/action_hooks/start)

```
export JAVA_HOME="$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/jdk/jdk1.8.0_05"
export PATH=$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/jdk1.8.0_05/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: Java 8 is present at `/etc/alternative/java_sdk_1.8.0` then what should be the problem?

Comment: What about your $JAVA_HOME / $PATH variables? They contain that given path? Your if your app's start action hook are setting their values.

Comment: Yes they have the above export lines. I restart the application from Openshift Web Console then SSH to app and run `java -version` it shows `java 7` version