# Openshift Jbossews Cartridge and Java 8 Support

Tags: java, openshift

I have taken upon a project that his hosted on Openshift, from what I have found it currently uses the Jbossews cartridge and has Java 7 installed.

I wish to upgrade to Java 8 but cannot seem to find a way.

I have tried to manually download the JDK, extract and export JAVA_HOME on the start and pre_build hooks and no luck.

To be honest, I am not even sure if my hooks are even being run, I'm not sure how I can check that.

I can't seem to find anything on Openshift themselves.

Comment: I have same problem. Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

As of now OpenShift does not support JDK 8. But you can use the DIY cartridge and install your own JDK version. Check this answer:

[JDK 8 support at DIY cartridge in OpenShift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23894323/jdk-8-support-at-diy-cartridge-in-openshift)

You can *SSH* into your gear and use the *printenv* command to check the environment:

```
printenv JAVA_HOME
```